# Can conics be dealt without calculus?

Tags: calculus

In Courant's What is mathematics？Stewart mentioned that Newton said that we can do everything without calculus as well as with calculus when talking about Analyse des infi-niment petits. So,(for Newton) can conics be dealt without calculus?

Comment: Probably almost all of the [many dozens of conics books from the 1800s](https://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:conics&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) do not use any calculus, and especially most any [book on geometrical conics](https://www.google.com/search?q=archive.org+%22geometrical+conics%22).

Answer (score 2):

Calculus makes it easier, but it is not needed. Apollonius wrote a whole book about conics using only synthetic geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The book *Conic Sections treated Geometrically* by W.H Besant is a great book, which as the title suggests treats Conic Sections by pure geometry.

Several results which are not even known to many, are proved using elementary Euclidian Geometry in all conics. Also, by conics, I assumed you are talking about the general second degree polynomial graphed on Cartesian Plane.